# How do I make images animate upwards with text animating downwards at the same time on hover?

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

I have these two images with corresponding labels: http://jsfiddle.net/Fdjtc/

I want to make it so that when I hover over one of the divs, the image animated downward and the text (initially invisible) animated downward and fades to full opacity, making the images and labels look like they do right now. How can I make sure that the images have enough space upwards to do this, and can I do this kind of animationg using CSS3's `transition`?

Comment: I have tried using `position: absolute` on the image, setting `top: 0.5em` on `img` and `top: 0` on `img:hover`. It does work for the image but I'm not sure how to handle the text in that way because I would need to hardcode the image size (which I don't want to). There must be some more elegant way, perhaps with margins or something.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Fdjtc/4/).

Comment: @mdesdev: No. Initially, the image should be vertically centered in the div. When hovered over, the image should be pushed up and the text pushed down so it looks like my fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/Fdjtc/9/**

There are several ways of doing this. This example is using absolute positioning with transitions on top/bottom.

**CSS**:

```
div.wrap > img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    -webkit-transition: top 500ms;
}

div.wrap:hover > img {
    top: 5px;
}

div.wrap > span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: bottom 500ms;
}

div.wrap:hover > span {
    bottom: 2px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Edit**: (*after your dynamic size request*)

This is another way of doing it, using margins. Text caption is a bit of problem here but you will get the idea.

Updated Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/Fdjtc/11/**

*CSS*:

```
div.wrap {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 4px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

div.wrap > img {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 16px;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top 500ms;
}

div.wrap:hover > img {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Of course! Never thought of using bottom for the text. Thanks!

Comment: Would prefer to get rid of the `<span>` but I guess you can't get everything in this world...

Comment: :) yup. this way it is simple. otherwise you may have to get into a lot of hacks which will make a mess of your clean code.

Comment: Wait, I just realized that this doesn't work without hardcoding the size. Is there some way I can do it without doing that?

Comment: Can you work with percentages? This method will work with defined width/height because the images are absolutely positioned with relative divs. At least images can work in percentage here, so you need not fix the image size. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fdjtc/10/

Comment: Oh well, I guess that's a less redundant solution, and I guess it will do :)

Comment: @user3075741: updated my answer. there you go, i have attempted the other method of using margins. this will free you from fixed sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote, I've came up with this for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fdjtc/6/

I've made quite a noticeable change to your html, too:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/256">
    <span>Label 1</span>
</div>
```

Hopefully this is what you wanted, if not, please extend your question and be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted to achieve ?

```
.box img
{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
    margin-top:-200px;
}
.box:hover > img
{
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4BtcR/